# Can we design a BPM in WSO2 BPS server directly without using eclipse?

Tags: wso2

I'm new to this area that is why a bit confused and curious.
I had already design BPMs for wso2 in eclipse using BPMN 2.0.
But is there any option available in BPS server to directly design those BPMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 BPS itself does not provide a way to develop BPMN. You need to use eclipse